# How to create a regular expression to replace a url?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression using re.sub() that can replace a URL from a string for example.

```
tool(id='merge_tool', server='http://localhost:8080')
```

I created a regular expression that returns a string something like given below.

```
 a = "https:192.168.1.1:8080"

 re.sub(r'http\S+', a, "tool(id='merge_tool', server='http://localhost:8080')")
```

results:

```
 "tool(id='merge_tool', server='https:192.168.1.1"
```

Or if I provide this URL:

```
 b = 'https:facebook.com'

 re.sub(r'http\S+', b, "tool(id='merge_tool', server='http://localhost:8080')")
```

Results:

```
 "tool(id='merge_tool', server='https:facebook.com"
```

How to fix this so that it can return the entire string after replacing the URL?

Comment: Try subtracting `'` from `\S`: `r"http[^\s']+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r"http[^\s']+", b.replace('\\', '\\\\'), "tool(id='merge_tool', server='http://localhost:8080')")
```

Note that

- `http[^\s']+` will match `http` and then any one or more chars other than whitespace and single quote
- `b.replace('\\', '\\\\')` is a must for cases where replacement literal string is dynamic, and all backslashes in it must be doubled to work as expected.